# Issue with python library Omnizart

Tags: python

I am using python 3.9.7 via Anaconda 2.2.0. I tried following the quick start instructions for [Omnizart](https://music-and-culture-technology-lab.github.io/omnizart-doc/quick-start.html).

But when I try to run `sudo apt-get install libsndfile-dev fluidsynth ffmpeg` on my cmd.exe terminal I get an error `'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Could someone assist me on how I should run Omnizart. Thanks

Comment: That is no wonder since this is a Linux (Debian based Linux distribution more exactly) command and you seem to be on Windows.

Comment: Noted with thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have been using UNIX commands in Windows OS. You can install the above-listed packages using the pip command. Make sure you have pip installed before running the below commands.

```
pip install --system package-name
```

In your case, you can try using,

```
pip install libsndfile fluidsynth ffmpeg
```

You can also use the anaconda package manager to install packages which is a lot simpler and faster way to manage. I'll add a link so you can read about this more [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/)

Comment: Thanks but I tried to pip install libsndfile and got the error `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libsndfile` and `ERROR: No matching distribution found for libsndfile`. The other 2 packages were fine. Is there a problem with the package that I do not know?

Comment: The 'libsndfile' package you are trying to install is not a Python package. You can try installing the 'pysoundfile' package. It is a Python wrapper for the above library.

pip install pysoundfile

I'm sure this will solve the issue

Comment: Thanks, was able to install pysoundfile successfully. But I was not able to run this command `omnizart download-checkpoints`. Would you be able to translate all the commands in the [quick start](https://music-and-culture-technology-lab.github.io/omnizart-doc/quick-start.html), so that I can run it on CMD.exe prompt on my Anaconda package installed on windows.